# ThreeJS - Trouble loading FBX file

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I've got some fairly simple ThreeJS, just trying to add an FBX object into my scene. However, whenever I run it I get "uncaught TypeError: THREE.fbxloader is not a constructor" at line 15, which is where I call the FBXLoader. I've tried replacing both the FBXLoader.js and Three.js files with the latest builds, but nothing has worked.

Here's my code:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
loader.load( 'thrown.fbx', function ( object ) {
    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( object );
    var action = mixer.clipAction( object.animations[ 0 ] );
    action.play();
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child.isMesh ) {
            child.castShadow = true;
            child.receiveShadow = true;
        }
    } );
    scene.add( object );
} );


var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper( 50, 50 );
scene.add( gridHelper );

camera.position.z = 20;
camera.position.y = 10;

var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
};

animate();
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Have been working at this for hours to no avail.

Comment: This generally means that the FBXLoader.js file has not loaded correctly. What do you get if you enter `console.log( typeof THREE.FBXLoader );`?

Comment: I get undefined. I figured that this may be the case, but I replaced both the fbxloader and threejs files with the latest build and I got the same error. really confusing.

Comment: Well, this is not a three.js issue, it's a problem with the way you're including the files in your HTML. Without seeing that, there's not much we can do to help you.